# cakephp auth redirect and referrer

Tags: cakephp

Let me explain the situation before I ask the question. I have a site, domain.com. the page sub.domain.com requires a user to be logged in to access. If I allow access to sub.domain.com/login which provides a form whose action is domain.com/login, it sends the data to domain.com/login and redirects back to sub.domain.com/login like it should. However, if I try to access sub.domain.com (which requires authentication) it redirects to domain.com/login correctly, but doesn't redirect back to sub.domain.com after logging in. I found the error to be that the redirect when not logged in wasn't sending the referrer header. Is there a way to make it so that if a user tries to access a page on a subdomain that requires authentication, that it will redirect him to domain.com/login, then back to where he originally was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it all had to do with routes. I finally was able to get it working by setting up a switch statement in my routes.php file:

```
switch(Configure::read('subdomain'))
{
     case 'subdomain':
          Router::connect('/login', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'));
}
```

And set up my bootstrap like so:

```
preg_match('/^(?:www\.)?(?:(.+)\.)?(.+\..+)$/i', env('HTTP_HOST'), $matches); 
$subdomain = empty($matches[1]) ? false : $matches[1];  
if( strlen($subdomain) > 0 && $subdomain != "www" ) 
{
    if($subdomain == 'api')
        $_GET["url"] =  $subdomain . "/" . (isset($_GET["url"]) ? $_GET["url"] : ""); 
    Configure::write('subdomain', $subdomain);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does redirect always need to redirect back to sub.domain.com? If so, i'd suggest setting the AuthComponents loginRedirect attribute to the location you want the user to be redirected to. See this page: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1270/loginRedirect

Also, that page says that CakePHP automatically stores the controller-action pair you were accessing before the login **in your session**. So maybe you should also check whether your session is shared between the domain.com and sub.domain.com.

One final comment: what **does** happen after login? Are you redirected to the controller/action on domain.com or aren't you redirected at all?

NOTE: I'm assuming you're using CakePHP 1.3 and use the AuthComponent for logging users in.

Comment: It's supposed to redirect you back to where you were, but it just redirects you to the login page again. My session is shared between the two, as once I'm logged in, I can manually go to sub.domain.com again and access it. I am using Cakephp 1.3 and AuthComponent

Comment: Does it actually redirect you to the login page again or does it redirect back to the subdomain which then redirects you back to the login page? (Which would probably go so fast you wouldn't notice)

You can find out by using httpfox (firefox-extension) which will show you all headers being sent.

Comment: i redirects to '/'. Found out, it has to do with the subdomain. sub.domain.com is '/' to cakephp. cake doesn't distinguish between domain.com and sub.domain.com